# Example of 3-regular graph with chromatic index > 3

Tags: graph-theory

folks.

For a homework assignment I've been asked to prove that a 3-regular Hamiltonian graph has a chromatic index of 3. I really would like to work through the proof myself, but am having trouble thinking of a 3-regular graph that's NOT Hamiltonian as a negative example.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The famous Petersen graph is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: And if you want more examples, read about snarks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: how many vertices has a 3-regular graph (parity). So how many colors do you need to edge-color the Hamiltonian cycle. Now finish the proof.

Comment: So I have that you can color the edges of the cycle with 2 colors since the 3-regular graph must have an even number of vertices. We are therefore coloring one edge into, and one edge out of, every vertex of the graph, leaving an independent set of uncolored edges. Give these edges a third color. 
Thank you for the help!